# Initialized string variable in Python?

Tags: python

Create a string variable that is initialized to your entire name??

Im a little lost

Thanks Kim:)

Comment: I would suggest [starting with the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html). If you have specific questions after that, then ask them.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Comment: You do not "initialize" strings per se. Python does not have primitive types, therefore literals are already considered objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to create a string variable with my name?  Sure, here it is:

```
  my_name = 'Samuel Robert Dolan'
```

If that's not what you want, please be more descriptive in your question. :)

Comment: I understand creating a string but Im unsure of what it means to initialize? The actual question states create a string variable that is initialized to your entire name first, middle, and last.

Comment: The `my_name` declaration initializes a variable and assigns it my entire name "Samuel" (First) "Robert" (middle) and "Dolan" (last).  That variable becomes of string type because of it's assigned to a string.

Comment: Python is **strongly** typed. It is also **dynamically** typed. Do not confuse the two